# How can I give each item in a list a different value?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to iterate through a list and give each item in the list a different value for Contract_Length__c. This is what I originally had:

```
for (Opportunity op : updateOpps) {
    for (Integer y = 1; y < 7; y ++) {
        op.Contract_Length__c = String.valueOf(y);
        op.stageName = 'Closed Won';
    }
}
```

Until I realized that this wouldn't give each of them a different value. I tried:

```
for (Integer y = 1; y < 7; y ++) {
    updateOpps[y].Contract_Length__c = String.valueOf(y);
    updateOpps[y].stageName = 'Closed Won';
}
```

How can I get the first item in the list of 6 to have a Contract_Length__c of 1, the next to have a Contract_Length__c of 2, and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
Integer y = 0;
for (Opportunity op : updateOpps) {
    op.Contract_Length__c = String.valueOf(y++);
}
```

Just define the helper variable `y` outside the loop. Iterate over `updateOpps` and increment `y` in each iteration.

Comment: Quick follow up question: How can I perform an update after this?

Should it be in the for loop? As in `update op` 

Or should it be after the for loop as in `update updateOpps`

Comment: `update updateOpps.values();` should do the trick.

Comment: Actually just update `updateOpps` worked fine, the `.values()` didn't work in my case. Thank you though.